# error in including GLAUX.h in Eclipse

Tags: opengl, eclipse-cdt

I am a newbie in OpenGL.

I am using Eclipse to do some OpenGL examples, but I can't include `glaux.h` in my file.
Eclipse always gives a warning that it can't find this library.

So, how can I import this library into Eclipse?

Comment: Does your code compile properly? What is your OS and compiler? How do you compile your project (managed builder, external `make`?)

Answer (score 0):

Would [this thread help](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=197378&S=8c867309d4ce49d7c2471ce211391d6e#page_top)?

> You should add the include path for the external library.
>   In `Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols`, go to the `Includes` tab.
>   Add the path for C (and C++ if your header contains C++ elements).

Once you pass this error, check out the blog post "[Was trying my hands at openGL...](http://agenthunts.blogspot.com/2008/03/was-trying-my-hands-at-opengl.html)".

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, its Eclipse scanners' job to add those automatically.

Comment: And this should be examined first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the libraries on your system? If not please download gluax.h from http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/glaux.h and gluax.lib from http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/glaux.lib.

Set the path and you are done.